# No inputs were found in config file ... Specified 'include' paths were '["**/*.(ts|tsx)"]' and 'exclude' paths were '[]'

Tags: typescript, cypress

I'm getting the error:

> No inputs were found in config file ... Specified 'include' paths were
> '["**/*.(ts|tsx)"]' and 'exclude' paths were '[]'.

and I have no idea why it's appearing. I've prepared a TS config file for Cypress only, which is different from the main one.

```
// cypress/tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "../../node_modules",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
    "types": ["cypress", "@types/testing-library__cypress"]
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.(ts|tsx)"
  ]
}
```

What should I do in order to resolve the error?